# How to copy the response received by a URL in excel via Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

Can we copy the response received in excel via JMeter?

[image]

Comment: i think this link useful just visit :-https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is using [Save responses to a file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener, if you add it as a child of the request and configure it like:

[image]

This will produce `response1.json` for first request, `response2.json` for second request, etc. Check out [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter/) article for more details.

Once done you should be able to [import the JSON files into Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-data-from-external-data-sources-power-query-be4330b3-5356-486c-a168-b68e9e616f5a)

[image]